# Python3 Subprocess 'Access Denied'

Tags: python-3.x, subprocess

I am trying to run VLC via the command line with a large number of arguments as I am encoding raw video from a capture card into a transport stream:

```
import os
import sys
import subprocess

comm_string = r'"G:\VLC\vlc" --ffmpeg-hw --avcodec-hw=any dshow:// :dshow-vdev="Video (00 Pro Capture HDMI 4K+)" :dshow-adev="Audio ' \
'(2- 00 Pro Capture HDMI 4K+)" :dshow-threads=8 :dshow-aspect-ratio=16\:9 :dshow-size="3840x2160" :dshow-pixel_format=yuv444p16le ' \
':dshow-tune=film :dshow-preset=lossless :dshow-profile=main10 show-vcodec=x265 :dshow-fps=50 :dshow-crf=0 :dshow-acodec=mp4a ' \
':dshow-stereo-mode=5 :dshow-force-surround-sound=0 :dshow-ab=128 :dshow-samplerate=44100 :no-dshow-config :live-caching=300 --sout ' \
'"#transcode{venc=ffmpeg,vcodec=mp2v,threads=8,aspect=16:9,width=3840,height=2160,fps=50,acodec=a52,ab=1500,channels=2,samplerate=48000,soverlay}' \
':standard{access=file,dst=-,mux=ts}"'


startupinfo = None
startupinfo = subprocess.STARTUPINFO()
startupinfo.dwFlags |= subprocess.STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW

process = subprocess.Popen([comm_string], startupinfo=startupinfo)
```

...this generates the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "G:/HTPC Scripts/NPVR Command Line/Command Line.py", line 17, in <module>
    process = subprocess.Popen([comm_string], startupinfo=startupinfo)
  File "G:\Python36\lib\subprocess.py", line 709, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "G:\Python36\lib\subprocess.py", line 997, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied
```

...it was my understanding that you can pass both the program and all it's attendant arguments into subprocess using a single string. Is this not the case? How should I amend my syntax if not?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution btw:

```
import os
import sys
import subprocess

os.chdir('G:\\VLC\\')

startupinfo = None
startupinfo = subprocess.STARTUPINFO()
startupinfo.dwFlags |= subprocess.STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW

process = subprocess.Popen([
'vlc',
'--ffmpeg-hw',
'--avcodec-hw=any',
'dshow:// :dshow-vdev="Video (00 Pro Capture HDMI 4K+)" :dshow-adev="Audio (2- 00 Pro Capture HDMI 4K+)"',
':dshow-threads=8',
':dshow-aspect-ratio=16\:9',
':dshow-size="3840x2160"',
':dshow-pixel_format=yuv444p16le',
':dshow-tune=film',
':dshow-preset=lossless',
':dshow-profile=main10',
'show-vcodec=x265',
':dshow-fps=50',
':dshow-crf=0',
':dshow-acodec=mp4a',
':dshow-stereo-mode=5',
':dshow-force-surround-sound=0',
':dshow-ab=128',
':dshow-samplerate=44100',
':no-dshow-config',
':live-caching=300',
'--sout',
'"#transcode{venc=ffmpeg,vcodec=mp2v,threads=8,aspect=16:9,width=3840,height=2160,fps=50,acodec=a52,ab=1500,channels=2,samplerate=48000,soverlay}:standard{access=file,dst=-,mux=ts}"',
], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, startupinfo=startupinfo)
```

Answer (score -2):

first of all why did you put r in every line of the string? it is a single string so using it once is fine. And also, do you care for the stdout? if you dont care i suggest you use either os.popen() or os.system()

Comment: hi - the repeated raw strings was an oversight on my part. i have amended the question now, however i still get the same outcome. why using os instead of subprocess though?

Comment: Please only post answers if you have a solution to the OP's problem. Otherwise post a comment.

Comment: @JBentley I will keep that in mind, but, my reputation is low so I am not allowed to comment on smth I didn't post.